# Is there such a thing as a double roller/bearing? Two rollers/bearings that share one axis, but can roll independently. [linear/pivot]

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bearings, linear-motion

I'm looking for two track rollers or bearings that share an axis, but can roll independently of each other. Ideally, they are compact as well ($\leq 1 \text{ in}.$ diameter) and can handle a moderate load ($50 \text{ lbs}$).

I have found these [Track Rollers](https://www.mcmaster.com/rollers/track-rollers-5/)

[image]

But I only need one pair instead of two pairs. Also I don't know if the left side and right side roll independently.

I want be able to linearly slide two guide rails

[image]

but also pivot them about the shared axis.

To do this, I would put one roller in one guide rail and the other roller in the other guide rail, then each guide rail would be able to slide along its own length **and** pivot about the shared axis. If there's another way to do this, I would like to know as well.

Comment: Check into the wheel for the sliding drawer. But you have to design the carriage to attach two wheels - they won't separate but would roll independently depending on how you attach the power supplies.

Comment: @r13 thanks, can you post a link to an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply google the word "drawer wheels" to get results that fit your need. The one shown has an OD of 1 1/8".

[image]